# Unable to push MERN App to heroku servers

Tags: node.js, heroku, npm

So I have this MERN app pushed to my github repo https://github.com/Banialczele/coursemanagement and now I would like to push that repo to heroku.
 
My problem is that when ever I try to deploy my app to heroku server it deploys to server, but when I want to visit that link I got an error. 
 However when I try to run `heroku local web` in my IDE my app runs perfectly, but when I want to deploy to server something is crushing all the time. This is what stacktrace looks like:

```
2020-03-14T12:25:20.748376+00:00 app[web.1]: [1] Error: Cannot find module 'express'
2020-03-14T12:25:20.748376+00:00 app[web.1]: [1] Require stack:
2020-03-14T12:25:20.748376+00:00 app[web.1]: [1] - /app/server/src/index.js
2020-03-14T12:25:20.748378+00:00 app[web.1]: [1]     at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:982:15)
2020-03-14T12:25:20.748379+00:00 app[web.1]: [1]     at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:864:27)
2020-03-14T12:25:20.748379+00:00 app[web.1]: [1]     at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1044:19)
2020-03-14T12:25:20.748380+00:00 app[web.1]: [1]     at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:77:18)
2020-03-14T12:25:20.748380+00:00 app[web.1]: [1]     at Object.<anonymous> (/app/server/src/index.js:1:17)
2020-03-14T12:25:20.748380+00:00 app[web.1]: [1]     at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1158:30)
2020-03-14T12:25:20.748380+00:00 app[web.1]: [1]     at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1178:10)
2020-03-14T12:25:20.748381+00:00 app[web.1]: [1]     at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1002:32)
2020-03-14T12:25:20.748381+00:00 app[web.1]: [1]     at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:901:14)
2020-03-14T12:25:20.748381+00:00 app[web.1]: [1]     at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:74:12) {
2020-03-14T12:25:20.748381+00:00 app[web.1]: [1]   code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
2020-03-14T12:25:20.748382+00:00 app[web.1]: [1]   requireStack: [ '/app/server/src/index.js' ]
2020-03-14T12:25:20.748382+00:00 app[web.1]: [1] }
2020-03-14T12:25:20.756503+00:00 app[web.1]: [1] npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
2020-03-14T12:25:20.756505+00:00 app[web.1]: [1] npm ERR! errno 1
2020-03-14T12:25:20.759707+00:00 app[web.1]: [1] npm ERR! teachercourseapp@1.0.0 server: `cd server/src && node index.js`
2020-03-14T12:25:20.760641+00:00 app[web.1]: [1] npm ERR! Exit status 1
2020-03-14T12:25:20.760642+00:00 app[web.1]: [1] npm ERR!
2020-03-14T12:25:20.760643+00:00 app[web.1]: [1] npm ERR! Failed at the teachercourseapp@1.0.0 server script.
2020-03-14T12:25:20.760644+00:00 app[web.1]: [1] npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
2020-03-14T12:25:20.769172+00:00 app[web.1]: [1]
2020-03-14T12:25:20.771168+00:00 app[web.1]: [1] npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
2020-03-14T12:25:20.771169+00:00 app[web.1]: [1] npm ERR!     /app/.npm/_logs/2020-03-14T12_25_20_761Z-debug.log
2020-03-14T12:25:20.779534+00:00 app[web.1]: [1] npm run server exited with code 1
2020-03-14T12:25:21.019553+00:00 app[web.1]: [0]
2020-03-14T12:25:21.019562+00:00 app[web.1]: [0] > coursemanagement@0.1.0 start /app/client
2020-03-14T12:25:21.019563+00:00 app[web.1]: [0] > react-scripts start
2020-03-14T12:25:21.019563+00:00 app[web.1]: [0]
2020-03-14T12:25:21.024669+00:00 app[web.1]: [0] sh: 1: react-scripts: not found
2020-03-14T12:25:21.029965+00:00 app[web.1]: [0] npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
2020-03-14T12:25:21.029966+00:00 app[web.1]: [0] npm ERR! syscall spawn
2020-03-14T12:25:21.030363+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! file sh
2020-03-14T12:25:21.030364+00:00 app[web.1]: [0] npm ERR! errno ENOENT
2020-03-14T12:25:21.031948+00:00 app[web.1]: [0] npm ERR! coursemanagement@0.1.0 start: `react-scripts start`
2020-03-14T12:25:21.031949+00:00 app[web.1]: [0] npm ERR! spawn ENOENT
2020-03-14T12:25:21.031949+00:00 app[web.1]: [0] npm ERR!
2020-03-14T12:25:21.033375+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Failed at the coursemanagement@0.1.0 start script.
2020-03-14T12:25:21.033376+00:00 app[web.1]: [0] npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
2020-03-14T12:25:21.037820+00:00 app[web.1]: [0] npm WARN Local package.json exists, but node_modules missing, did you mean to install?
2020-03-14T12:25:21.038198+00:00 app[web.1]: [0]
2020-03-14T12:25:21.038591+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
2020-03-14T12:25:21.038592+00:00 app[web.1]: [0] npm ERR!     /app/.npm/_logs/2020-03-14T12_25_21_032Z-debug.log
2020-03-14T12:25:21.047517+00:00 app[web.1]: [0] npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
2020-03-14T12:25:21.047518+00:00 app[web.1]: [0] npm ERR! errno 1
2020-03-14T12:25:21.048896+00:00 app[web.1]: [0] npm ERR! teachercourseapp@1.0.0 client: `cd client/src && npm start`
2020-03-14T12:25:21.048897+00:00 app[web.1]: [0] npm ERR! Exit status 1
2020-03-14T12:25:21.048897+00:00 app[web.1]: [0] npm ERR!
2020-03-14T12:25:21.049322+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Failed at the teachercourseapp@1.0.0 client script.
2020-03-14T12:25:21.049753+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
2020-03-14T12:25:21.055102+00:00 app[web.1]: [0]
2020-03-14T12:25:21.055708+00:00 app[web.1]: [0] npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
2020-03-14T12:25:21.055709+00:00 app[web.1]: [0] npm ERR!     /app/.npm/_logs/2020-03-14T12_25_21_050Z-debug.log
2020-03-14T12:25:21.060294+00:00 app[web.1]: [0] npm run client exited with code 1
2020-03-14T12:25:21.067946+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
2020-03-14T12:25:21.068281+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! errno 1
2020-03-14T12:25:21.069285+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! teachercourseapp@1.0.0 start: `concurrently "npm run client" "npm run server" `
2020-03-14T12:25:21.069440+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Exit status 1
2020-03-14T12:25:21.069684+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!
2020-03-14T12:25:21.069864+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Failed at the teachercourseapp@1.0.0 start script.
2020-03-14T12:25:21.070045+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
2020-03-14T12:25:21.075605+00:00 app[web.1]:
2020-03-14T12:25:21.075900+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
2020-03-14T12:25:21.076095+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     /app/.npm/_logs/2020-03-14T12_25_21_070Z-debug.log
2020-03-14T12:25:21.194915+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2020-03-14T12:25:21.175761+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2020-03-14T12:25:22.079114+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=managingcourses.herokuapp.com request_id=175c1aa8-0966-4493-a328-ed303e4b8075 fwd="188.123.215.228
" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2020-03-14T12:25:22.577434+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=managingcourses.herokuapp.com request_id=912f071c-c6c0-49ce-996d-33005e324fb1 fwd="188.
123.215.228" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

It starts with cannot find `express` module, but I've reinstalled it with --save flag and nothing changes. Could you please help me try to figure this out? I'm stack for like 2 days with that error.

Comment: If you installed express with `--save` it should appear in the `package.json` in dependencies. As it is not the case, heroku never installed it before launching your server.

Comment: @L.Meyer thanks for quick response. In ``package.json`` file I can see express in dependencies. When you click on my github repo and go to /server/package.json it shows express in dependencies, that's why I'm confused.

Comment: Heroku is looking at the root, so the scanned package.json is this one : https://github.com/Banialczele/coursemanagement/blob/master/package.json

Comment: ahh, I see. Thanks for help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following the comment, I post where the problem is:
Heroku is looking at the `package.json` located at the root of your project. You installed express in the server folder but the file at the root does not contain it.

Either you can push a subtree of your repository:

```sh
git subtree push --prefix path/to/subdirectory heroku master
```

Or just split up your server and client parts into two repositories.

Comment: Can I just instead install all dependecies in ``package.json`` in root of project ? I mean I guess It's bad idea. but for now I'm trying everything...

Comment: Yes, you could but heroku wouldn't be able to launch both client and server at the same time on one app.

Comment: By the way there is a package.json inside `/server/models` which shouldn't be here and you will need a secured mongo database in order to make your project work.

Comment: Hey @L. Meyer, once more, could you please help me figure it out? App still doesn't work, it always returns "something is already running on port" even if in my server I define my port value as ``  process.env.PORT || 5000; ``

Comment: I still see `concurrently` in the start of your `package.json`, it's a problem as heroku cannot listen simultaneously on two different ports: your server and your client.

Comment: I've tried to apply the way BradTraversy did here https://github.com/bradtraversy/mern_shopping_list and he uses ``concurrently`` in his entry folder